# Hibernate Data Exception not coming

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a POJO class as follows,

```
Public class RateUp{
int id;
String rate;
}
```

and in hbm file,

```
<property name="rate" column="RATE" type="string" length="4"/>
```

In database,the data type of rate column is **character** and length is **4**

and when i save the data as follows,

```
Rateup obj = new Rteup();
obj.setRate("444444");
session.saveorupdate(obj);
```

there is no exception even the length of the string is longer than defined.

when `transaction.commit` happens it is throwing **DATAEXCEPTION** but i want hibernate to throw the exception when `saveorupdate` happens

Thanks

Comment: `rate` is in int type, how can you set string? java is wondering

Comment: sorry edited the post

Comment: `saveorupdate` does not go to db till transaction commits, so dataexception is coming from db when you commit, which makes sense. Since your column size is 4 in the db table.

Answer (score 0):

That length after all will be string length in databse. Corresponding jpa for this is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#length%28%29)

So if you make length  = 4 and save string with length 5 then only 4 characters will be saved, rest of them will be thrown away. This is not something hibernate manages during save, it is just database column definition. So database cuts your string if it more than expected length. Once you save it, go to db and you should see 4 characters, not 5. You can also column definition which length = 4

I think hibernate [validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en-US/html_single/) does whatever you are looking for, there is `@Size` annotation. Check the reference.

If you were use validation, it would be something like:

```
    Public class RateUp{
      int id;
      @Size(min = 0, max = 4)
      String rate;
    }

    Rateup obj = new Rteup();
    obj.setRate("444444");

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Rateup>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(obj);
    if(constraintViolations.size()>0){
     system.out.print(constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
    }
    session.saveorupdate(obj);
```

Comment: when tranaction.commit happens it is throwing DATAEXCEPTION but i want hibernate to throw the exception when saveorupdate happens

Comment: Who is throwing data exception now?

Comment: Hibernate is throwing dataexception but it should throw when saveOrUpdate hapens right..? Not during commit

Comment: no, it does not. I am telling you, read my post, Hibernate does not do anything with length, all it does is for creating table it creates string column with length = 4. So only db may throw it when you save it, really save happens when you commit transaction.

Comment: How to restrict data without exceeding the suggested length before saveorUpdate?

Comment: Is it ok to use @size when hbm mappings are in xml file.Whether it will work?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-xmlconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

The data is not inserted to the database until the transaction is committed. What about using session.flush() to force data insertion if you do want the exception before transaction committed?